# Java EE scheduled task and forced task

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlets, batch-file

I'm working on a Java EE Web application.
I've developed a Scheduled Batch using @WebListener annotation:

```
@WebListener
public class BatchServlet implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        context = sce.getServletContext();
        schedulerEngine = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        schedulerEngine.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyThread(), 0, 300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


public class MyThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...... //my business logic
        }
```

and it works correctly.

But, for my purpose, I need to force the MyThread() batch on demand, for example, when I received a particular request within a Servlet. Obviosly I can call the MyBatch thread separately, but I was wondering that there are some best practices to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options: create a regular thread pool (with multiple threads) and just put tasks on the executor queue whenever they come in.

If you need more fine-grained control, you can share something like a concurrent queue between the servlet and the one thread that you have. Let this thread read from the queue, it will block automatically when the queue is empty.

Then your servlet can put work on this queue, if the thread happened to be blocked on getting an item it will automatically wake up.

You might wanna look up the "producer-consumer" pattern. There is a lot of literature about this.